# GitHub Graphql : Getting sponsor tier information for the sponsors of a user

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I am using the GitHub graphql for getting the sponsor information of a user. While I am able to get the sponsors for a particular user, I am unable to get the sponsorship-tier information for the sponsors. The graphql query that I have written is as follows:

```
{
  user(login: <<loginID>>) {
    name
    sponsorshipsAsMaintainer(first: 1) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        createdAt
        privacyLevel
        tier {
          createdAt
          name
          description
        }
        sponsor {
          login
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results i get for a user are as follows. Ideally, in the query I was hoping to get the tier information but the result returns a `null` for the `tier` field.

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "name": "XXX",
      "sponsorshipsAsMaintainer": {
        "totalCount": 11,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "createdAt": "2020-02-16T10:39:14Z",
            "privacyLevel": "PUBLIC",
            "tier": null,
            "sponsor": {
              "login": "XXX"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help or information to get the tier information for a sponsor would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi there! Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To date `tier` is still `null` and I haven't figured out what's the issue with that.

However I managed to fetch the tiers information using the following query:

```
query getTiers($login: String!) {
  user(login: $login) {
    sponsorshipsAsSponsor(first: 1) {
      nodes {
        sponsorable {
          sponsorsListing {
            tiers(first: 5) {
              nodes {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following query to look up sponsors, and I only get tier information for my own tiers. I assume the viewer's databaseId must match the sponsorable databaseId to see this information

```
query {
  user(login: "${login}") {
    sponsorshipsAsSponsor(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        privacyLevel
        tier {
          monthlyPriceInDollars
        }
        sponsorable {
          ... on User {
              databaseId
          }
          ... on Organization {
              databaseId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a user that is sponsoring three other projects besides mine (I replaced the other project's databaseIds)

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "sponsorshipsAsSponsor": {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "privacyLevel": "PUBLIC",
                        "tier": {
                            "monthlyPriceInDollars": 3
                        },
                        "sponsorable": {
                            "databaseId": 220908 <--- Me
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "privacyLevel": "PUBLIC",
                        "tier": null,
                        "sponsorable": {
                            "databaseId": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "privacyLevel": "PUBLIC",
                        "tier": null,
                        "sponsorable": {
                            "databaseId": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "privacyLevel": "PUBLIC",
                        "tier": null,
                        "sponsorable": {
                            "databaseId": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```